# Showing a progressbar from within a fragemnet

Tags: android

I have a fully working app which contains a fragment declared as follows:

```
public class SearchableListFragment extends Fragment implements TabListener
```

At one point during the work of the fragment, we execute a rather slow loop. Imagine something like:

```
for(int i = 0;i < large_number;i++)
{
    // do complex maths
}
```

but this loop takes rather a long time and I'd like to have a progress bar appear during the loop. I have seen a variety of examples of adding dialogs, but they all seem to fail because one part or another appears not to apply to fragments.... or they are not applicable because they assume one thing or another that simply does not apply in my case. How can I wrap my loop in some code that will display a progress bar (either a linear bar or a swirling circle - whatever's easiest).

**EDIT:** The fragment is deployed within a `SherlockFragmentActivity`. Also the fragments are being implemented via `android.support.v4.app.*`

Comment: You could inflate an XML, which has a progressbar defined or use the standard documented progressbar class? (I had problems with the later too, the first way worked everytime)

Comment: Inflating xml sounds like more work than is needed... taking the standard appearance is fine. But the "standard documented progressbar" didn't want to work inside a fragment as far as I could tell.

Comment: what "does not work inside a fragment" ? There could be so many problems! YOu have to be more specific.

Comment: You really need to be specific, because I do think ProgressDialog should work according to your needs.

Comment: inflating a progressbar xml is as easy as doing the following:
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
mLayoutInflater.inflate(resource, root);

Comment: @Aeefire: Well just as one example I saw one suggestion of using ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),"HI", "Loading"); which I can put inside an activity no problem, but if I put it in a *fragment* then it says getParent() is undefined for a searchableListfragment. There were other examples too where the example code would compile without error in an activity but would complain something was undefined in a fragment.

Comment: Have you tried  `ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"HI", "Loading");` ? `show()` method just requires `Context` as first argument.

Comment: See M-WaJeEh 's answer. It's all about context.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this question: [addView not visible in custom FrameLayout but clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864896/addview-not-visible-in-custom-framelayout-but-clickable)

Especially its "SOLUTION" ( http://pastebin.com/2xjnCDLS ), which is a viewgroup which switches between the progressbar and the contentview(s), and is easily usable in your layout-xml, was very helpful for me in various occasions. Just call showProgressbar() before and showNext() after you've loaded your content/made your computations.

Answer (score 0):

I have this ModalProgress class that I use every where to show modal progress, I guess you can use it as it is:

```
public class ModalProgress extends DialogFragment {

public static void show(Activity activity, String title,
        String message) {
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }
    FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    hideInternal(ft, fm); 
    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ModalProgress();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("message", message);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}

private static void hideInternal(FragmentTransaction ft, FragmentManager fm) {
    Fragment prev = fm.findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
}

public static void hide(FragmentActivity activity) {
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }
    FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    hideInternal(ft, fm);
    ft.commit();
}

public ModalProgress() {
    setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    String title = args.getString("title");
    String msg = args.getString("message");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        dialog.setTitle(title);
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
        dialog.setMessage(msg);
    }
    return dialog;
} 
}
```

Now move your loop code inside AsyncTask:

```
private class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected void onPreExecute (){
          ModalProgress.show(getActivity(), "Working", "Please wait..."); 
     }
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) { 
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             // your loop here
         }
         return null;
     } 
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          ModalProgress.hide(getActivity());
     }
}
```

and then just execute `AsyncTask`.